# Is it possible to feed JasperReport values straight from the java application? What's the most simple way to do it?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there a way to give JasperReport a value from a label or a text field? I was wondering if it's possible to skip the hash maps, parameters, beans and such since it's such a simple task and im guessing i've missed something and there's probably a more efficient way to do it.

Example: A text field (text_field1) has the value "Random 50",
the jasper report template has a text field that's named $F{report_text} .
What's the most simple way to do it?

Comment: The HashMap is probably the simplest solution available to you based on your needs

Comment: @randomdavid Your question is unclear. `Is there a way to give JasperReport a value from a label or a text field?` - What do you mean?